# How to page an API response to other system expecting only one response?

Tags: c#, api, pagination, response

I'm working with the integration between two systems (*A* and *B*), and I'm responsible for the *A* side (C#).
On that scenario, *B* client consumes *A* API, where each endpoint delivers **all data** related to the that endpoint (for example, the endpoint **Clients** will deliver all clients in only one response).

The issue is that in some endpoints the amount of data may (it will) increase very much, and I need to find some way of sending it parceled, preferably not needing to change *B* implementation (there are many *B*s).

One big detail on that challenge is that *B* side can't click on *Next* or similar to the next page, it's a system.

Some idea/library/tip that can help me?

**Actual Scenario**: ClientController delivers all 10000 clients in one response.

**Expected Scenario**: Send 100 clients at a time, sending the next 100 just after the response that the previous 100 arrived ok.

Comment: What protocol are you using? TCP or http?  TCP you can partition data any way you want so data doesn't need to be broken into responses.  With http you get one response for every request.

Comment: That comment really helps, showed me what it's no possible to do. The protocol is **http**, **AspNetCore.Mvc** responses.

Comment: Where did you say that you were using ASP or HTTP?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that on the question, the issue is more related with web architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query string:

```
/your_api/clients?limit=100&start=0"
```

so on system **B** side you will iterate over that and pull as much as
you need at that moment, by changing `start=` and/or `limit=`

**Edit**:
no need to do any kind of mambo jumbo, query string is good thing, if you change that, there is no need to update consumers, like when you're changing API, so if there is some third system who don't need your change, they don't need to be updated.

If you need to update system **B** if you want to optimize it, do it.
Mambo jumbo is not good thing for quality and sustainable API.

Comment: The problem originally is that **B** side can't iterate, like saying "*send me the next page*", but it seems that we will end up with something like that, **B** side iterating.

Comment: That will not break anything on consumer side, you will just gave them the opportunity to chose if they want to do paging/iteration, if they don't want to cool stay as you are. 
If you implement something complex and not intuitive, for new consumers that would be weird.

Comment: Don't let one consumer design your api/system, give them all your system is meant for, but don't design it specifically for them

Comment: I understand that point, that's the reason we recently changed the architecture o *A* side. Anyway, I need to make it the easiest way for everybody, if it gets to hard/complex to iterate with my API, I lose partners.
With that idea in mind, I'm thinking now how to maintain the delivered data consistent, because on each minute records can be created/modified. By that way, when the client request *page 2*, records from *page 1* may not be the same.
Would it be viable to retrieve all data from DB, hold on server RAM for a while and send that data paged?

Comment: Sounds like a good fit for caching, take a look on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/caching-in-net-framework-applications
or maybe Redis, depends on your infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

If you have an object to share like a big video, you can use "range" requests and return pieces of total bytes. This won't work with a request which changes results, cause obviously it will expect multiple pieces requests and the result won't be understandable till you have every bit of the response.

Another idea can be to have an ID for every object in response and ask for a response starting by the last known ID given as parameter of the request.